# Distance function and Green's function

Tags: geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry

Let $ (M,g) $ be a two dimensional Riemmanian manifold, with a smooth distance function $ d(x,y) $ for all $ x, y$ in $ M$. The logarithm of the distance function then satisfies $ \Delta \left( \frac{1}{4 \pi} \log(d(x,y)) \right) = \delta(x-y) $, where $ \Delta $ is the laplace operator induced by the metric.

What is the easiest way to show this?

Comment: would it be good enough to specialize to $\mathbb{R}^2$? if you can transfer the problem to that setting, Fourier transform can handle the rest.

Comment: How should we interpret $x-y$ when $x$ and $y$ are points in an arbitrary Riemannian manifold? What is $\delta$ here?